# Passing variable through partial and Ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking to find out how I can pass a variable through an Ajax call with Rails, using a `.js.erb file`.

At the moment I am declaring this in my view

```
<% document = @documents.select { |d| d.skill_id == s.id } %> 

<div class="doc_upload">
  <%= render partial: 'shared/documents/document_form', locals: { document: document } %>
</div>
```

shared/documents/document_form

```
<% if document %>
  <% document.each do |doc| %>
    <%= doc %>
  <% end %>
  <%= render template: '/documents/new' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render template: '/documents/new' %>
<% end %>
```

So when I create a new document I am handling it with an Ajax call

create.js.erb

```
$('.doc_upload').html("<%= j render(partial: 'shared/documents/document_form', locals: { document: document }) %>")
```

However I get an `undefined local variable or method`document'`

Is there a reason I can't access `document` any more?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `document` variable is not defined. You need to either pass in `@document` found in the controller or initialize `document` in the js.erb file.

edit:
check your js.erb, in the `local` hash, you can clearly see that you're passing `document` variable but it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: thanks for the help...how can i access the local hash?

Comment: you misunderstood me. If you check your `create.js.erb`, you've written something like this -> `<%= j render(partial: 'shared/documents/document_form', locals: { document: document })`
as you can see, you have a parameter named `locals` which has the hash of `{ document: document }`. Just change it to `local: { document: @document }` and if your code is ok, it will be all good.

Comment: Another tip, you can rephrase that into something like this:
`<%= j render 'shared/documents/document_form`, document: @document` %>

Comment: ah i see, but i thought it would be able to access it from the `document` declaration in my view, but im now thinking that because im only rendering the partial with the ajax call, anything outside of that partial is no longer accessible? so how would i pass through the document variable?

Comment: the `js.erb` is a separate view. It doesn't know anything about the current view you've used the `AJAX`. The only thing it knows is the controller action, which is, `create`. So redefine `@document` in your create action in your controller and you'll be good.

Comment: if this answers your question, can you mark this as `answered`

Comment: Hi, well it does and it doesn't, would you mind looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256604/accessing-values-through-ajax-called-partials and maybe giving me a pointer please

Answer (score 0):

in create.js.erb change

```
$('.doc_upload').html("<%= j render(partial: 'shared/documents/document_form', locals: { document: document }) %>")
```

with

```
$('.doc_upload').html("<%= j render(partial: 'shared/documents/document_form', locals: { document: @document }) %>")
```

& it will work.